# Perform calculations on a dataset from csv

Tags: r, mean

I'm quite new with all this programming languages and I feel quite lost.

I opened a .csv file in R, where all years are in the same, this is just a chunk of all data:

```
airportTraffic
Month Passengers.at.London.airports Year.on.year.percentage.change  X
7   1999 July                      10460189                     6.77692529 NA
8    1999 Aug                      10746562                    5.892825629 NA
9   1999 Sept                       9956556                    4.322969061 NA
10   1999 Oct                       9504010                    7.631548966 NA
11   1999 Nov                       7645826                    6.264996409 NA
12   1999 Dec                       7056812                   -0.558869252 NA
13   2000 Jan                       6884793                         Jan-00 NA
14   2000 Feb                       7255968                    8.093845417 NA
15   2000 Mar                       8615850                    2.930832048 NA
16   2000 Apr                       9064285                    10.90525032 NA
17   2000 May                       9390592                    9.099764108 NA
18  2000 June                      10056169                    5.085494433 NA
```

As all years are in the same file, I would like to know how to get mean for year  1999 and also the rest of the years. I was able to get the mean for all the data, writing:

```
mean(airportTraffic$Passengers.at.London.airports).
```

Hope this is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I use the dplyr package for data frames.

e.g.

```
library(dplyr)
airportTraffic %>%
group_by(year) %>%
summarise(mean = mean(Passengers.at.London.airports))
```